# Monitoring the first div in list

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a Greasemonkey script. He must watch the page that occasionally appear coupons and take them.

Coupons are presented with a list of 
I would like to keep track of the first element, and for this use MutationObserver.
The problem is that the site uses ajax and the first coupon becomes the second, and so on. And MutationObserver continues to monitor it and does not notice the new coupon. Help, please, how I can only look at the top (first) in the list element div?

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('.id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Update:

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('.id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0].textContent);
    document.getElementsByClassName('nameshop')[0].click();
  });    
});
```

It gives a new element with the *div class = "id"* and click where I want. But that happens if I make changes through Firebug. If the site is updated, the script did not notice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the mutations-result this way: It offers an addedNodes-Property. So if a Node is added, just use mutations.addedNodes (of Type NodeList). For this, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0]);
  });    
});
```